# NetBeans 8.0.2, PHPUnit skeleton genertor 2.0.1 - phpunit tests were not generated for the following files

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

I'm trying to get a PHPUnit test generated via the NetBeans IDE. WHen I initiate the creation of a test, the output window shows:

"C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\phpunit-skelgen.bat" "--ansi" "generate-test" "PrintuiInterface" "C:\xampp\htdocs\unified\components\com_printui\interface\printui_interface.php" "PrintuiInterfaceTest" "C:\unittests\components\com_printui\interface\printui_interfaceTest.php"
phpunit-skelgen 2.0.1 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Done.

It seems successful but I also get a popup that states "Tests were not generated for the following files: printui_interface.php Review the log in Output window"

I've tried moving the 'unittests' directory to several different places, thinking it may be a permissions issue. I seem to get the same results no matter where I put the 'unittests' directory.

There are no errors in the PHP error log.

Any thoughts on how I can determine what is wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards.

Comment: I've also searched my laptop for the printui_interfaceTest.php file and it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: I also found the following n the Netbeans IDE log: INFO [org.netbeans.modules.php.phpunit.commands.SkeletonGenerator]: FileObject for generated test not found (java.io.File for test file exists: false)

Comment: SOLVED. It seems I needed a bootstrap.php file to load all the classes needed in generating/running the tests. Once I did that, everything came to life. I thought the NetBeans Include path would take care of that but I was wrong.